# Issue with number of solutions of equation of complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I' have a problem about number of solutions of complex variables. For example
$$z^{11} = \bar z.$$
If it depends on module I should Say $2$. But if it depends on argument I should say $12$.

For another example, say
$$z^6 = \bar z^2.$$
My solution to equation 1 is to divide them and after that I will have $$|z|^{10}(\cos(12a) + i \sin(12a)) = 1$$
So I should divide solution by $12$ or by $10$?
bar z.$$ 
$$z^{11} = \bar z.$$

Comment: In general, polynomials degree $n$ have $n$ roots (counting multiplicity). You are doing with functions which are NOT polynomials (because of conjugates). Such functions may or may not have as many roots as their "degree".

Answer (score 1):

Let $r= |z|\geq 0$. Since $$r^{11}=|z|^{11}=|z^{11}|= |\overline{z}| = |z|=r$$ we have $r= 0$ or $r^{10}=1$ so $$(r-1)(r^{9}+...+r^2+r+1)=0\implies r=1$$

If $r=0$ then $z=0$. If $r= 1$ then $\overline{z} ={1\over z}$ and so $$z^{11}= {1\over z} \implies z^{12}=1$$
Since last equation has 12 solution we have total 13 solution.